# How do you sample from a Poisson distribution when the observed count is zero?

Tags: simulation, poisson-distribution, monte-carlo, count-data

I have some data showing the count of deaths in a population. The data are stratified by age. For example, the data might show that at age 40 there were 30,000 years of observation and 300 deaths.

In some cases there are zero deaths; principally because there is little observation time. For example, the data might show that at age 70 there was 10 years of observation and 0 deaths.

I am using a Monte-Carlo method in which I create simulations by sampling each count from a Poisson distribution. This works fine, except for the observations of 0 deaths. In these cases, every simulation has 0 deaths.

I can see why this happens - in a Poisson distribution the mean equals the variance, so 0 deaths implies 0 variance; plus any simulation in which the count is greater than zero would mean that the mean of the simulations exceeds the observed count.

How can I deal with this? The only solution I have thought of is to "correct" the observed count from 0 to something like 0.5, as a way of acknowledging the risk is not actually zero. I would then create my simulations by sampling from a Poisson distribution with lambda of 0.5.

Comment: Do you have data for every age (i.e. 70, 71, etc) or decades of age (60s, 70s etc) or something else?

Comment: There are many solutions, but which to use depends primarily on *why* you are performing this simulation.  What do you hope to achieve with it?

Comment: @PeterFlom I've got data for each single year of age.

Comment: @whuber I'm doing the simulation tool allow an estimate of uncertainty in my analysis. I'm doing a life table analysis for which there is no obvious method of estimating an uncertainty interval. I'm therefore using a Monte Carlo method in which I simulate multiple datasets. Each count is sampled from a Poisson distribution.

Comment: It looks like you either have to accept that this resampling method will not capture the uncertainty in the low-count cases or else perform some initial analysis in which you estimate the uncertainty in the individual Poisson parameters.

Comment: Then you can try combining ages.